# Getting foreign key constraint conflict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm getting a foreign key constraint conflict when I try to populate my database with data, however I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong with the relation ship. (just recently got into sqlalchemy.)

I have 2 tables. One called `tInspectionType` and another called `tSection`. They are related via the section ID (`tSection.ixSection`) which is the `primary key` and in my `tInspectionType` table I have `ixSection` as a `foreign key`.

Here is what the relationship and tables look like:
`tSection`:

```
class TSection(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tSection'

    ixSection = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sSection = Column(Unicode(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        rep = ("<TSection(ixSection:{s.ixSection},"
               " sSection={s.sSection!r})>").format(s=self)
        return rep
```

Then my `tInspectionType` table

```
class TInspectionType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tInspectionType'

    ixInspectionType = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ixSection = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tSection.ixSection'), nullable=False)

    #ixDeviceType = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tDeviceType.ixDeviceType'), nullable=False)

    sInspectionType = Column(Unicode(255))

    section = relationship('TSection',
                            uselist=False,
                            backref=backref('inspection'))


    def __repr__(self):
        rep = ("<TInspectionType(ixInspectionType:{s.ixInspectionType},"
               " ixSection={s.ixSection},"
               " sInspectionType={s.sInspectionType!r})>").format(s=self)
        return rep
```

The Error occurs when I try to insert dummy data as follow:

```
pts.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

sections = [pts.TSection(sSection='Generic Header'),
            pts.TSection(sSection='Circuit Breaker Data'),
            pts.TSection(sSection='Trip Unit Data'),
            pts.TSection(sSection='Sensor Data'),
            pts.TSection(sSection='Trip Unit Results'),
            pts.TSection(sSection='Insulation Resistance'),
            pts.TSection(sSection='Contact Resistance'),
            pts.TSection(sSection='Breaker Inspection'),
            pts.TSection(sSection='Cell Inspection'),]

# Inspection Types
bkr_insp_types = [pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Inspect Contacts - Main'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Inspect Contacts - Arcing'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Inspect Insulators - Bus'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Inspect Insulators - Barrier'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Clean & Inspect Arc Chutes'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Clean Breaker'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Racking Mechanism'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Manual Close'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Electrical Close'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Tripping Manual'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Tripping Electrical'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Tripping Protection'),]

for ins in bkr_insp_types:
    ins.section= sections[7]
```

I cannot seem to see where I am going wrong. Not sure if it's in my table setup where I am going wrong or when populating the tables

Comment: So why be secretive about the error report? "My program goes wrong" doesn't really help much in deciding what the cause might be.

Comment: sorry, not secretive, more like forgetting. Will post it

Comment: actually I can close this question because I just figured out what my problem was. I will post the answer(pretty simple but I overlooked it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice that there was another place where  I needed to assign the section( the previous relationship was to a table called `tDeviceType` and it was still being assigned a `DeviceType` which doesn't exist in my table setup anymore)
[image]

This is the correct code:

```
# Inspection Types
bkr_insp_types = [pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Inspect Contacts - Main'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Inspect Contacts - Arcing'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Inspect Insulators - Bus'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Inspect Insulators - Barrier'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Clean & Inspect Arc Chutes'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Clean Breaker'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Racking Mechanism'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Manual Close'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Electrical Close'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Tripping Manual'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Tripping Electrical'),
                  pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Tripping Protection'),]

for ins in bkr_insp_types:
    ins.section = sections[0]

cell_insp_types = [pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Inspect Insulators - Barrier'),
                    pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Interlock'),
                    pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Clean Cell'),
                    pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Racking Mechanism'),
                    pts.TInspectionType(sInspectionType='Drawout Rails or Pan'),]

for ins in cell_insp_types:
    ins.section = sections[0]
```